# Check range of cells for a string from another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-drive

Cell A1 has a string.
Cells B1:G6 contain various strings.

Cell A2 wants to return "YES" if the string in A1 can be found in the range B1:G6, and "" if it can't.

I tried:
IF(CELL("contents", B1:G6)=CELL("contents", A2), "YES", "")

but that didn't work. Probably because it's searching the whole range if it contains only the string from A2.

Halp?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match or only that the string in A1 is contained in the search range?

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for a partial string in an array of strings, you'll want to use `match` with wildcards -

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&A1&"*",B1:B5,)),"","yes")
```

This would work if the range you are searching is in only 1 column as `match` only searches one column. So you could set up that formula with several `match` criteria for each column.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking only for cells that completely match the contents of `A1`
(case independent, but not finding partial matches), put

```
=SUM(--(A1=B1:G6))
```

into `A2` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
This will count the number of times the string in `A1` appears in `B1:G6`. 
If you want a TRUE/FALSE result, just check whether the above is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `COUNTIF`, e.g.

`=IF(COUNTIF(B1:G6,A1),"YES","")`

That will give you "YES" only if A1 matches (completely) any of the B1:G6 entries, although it isn't case-sensitive.

For a partial match you can use the same with wildcards like this

`=IF(COUNTIF(B1:G6,"*"&A1&"*"),"YES","")`